# How to create a composite key in SQL using the same attribute several times

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

does anyone know how to insert multiple staff_id values? The TABLE author is my intersection table between my tables Articles and Staff. I want to insert 2 staff members in this case. So for my wanted outcome, I want it to say staff_id 1 and 2 worked on the article_id 1.

[image]

Here is the output of the code above. I mean it works but it would create too many rows in my opinion.

[image]

I want it to say in one row, staff_id 1 and 2, wrote article_id 1.

I tried to create a composite key using this code

```sql
CREATE TABLE author(
staff_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Staff(staff_id),
staff_id INTEGER REFERENCES Staff(staff_id),
staff_id INTEGER REFERENCES Staff(staff_id),
staff_id INTEGER REFERENCES Staff(staff_id),
staff_id INTEGER REFERENCES Staff(staff_id),
staff_id INTEGER REFERENCES Staff(staff_id),
PRIMARY KEY (staff_id, staff_id, staff_id, staff_id, staff_id, staff_id)
);
```

but it gives me an error of "column "staff_id" appears twice in primary key constraint".

Comment: They are not *too many rows*. This is the proper way to do it.

Comment: Your approach with the link table is fine. It's a clean and standard way to create a many-to-many relationship. Don't worry about the number of rows.

Comment: So, what happens when you get 8 staff write one article?  The way you have it is actually the best way to do it.  Yes it creates multiple rows--one for each staff on an article, but it is normalized and easier to query.  Imagine if you have to find all the articles a particular staff wrote.

Comment: Column names must be unique within a table. You cannot have multiple `staff_id` columns.

Comment: out of curiosity: how many rows do you consider "too many"? 10 million? 100 million? one billion?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me like you are modelling a many to many relationship with staff_if and article_id. In which case, your first table author is the correct solution.

It may seem like a lot of rows, but each row signifies a different relation between a article and a staff.

Database Management Systems are very optimised to handle large amounts of data so I wouldn't worry about performance too much in this kind of scenario.